# Selenium, what is the best practice to deal with element is not clickable

Tags: selenium, click, webdriver, element, wait

I am using selenium 2.46 (firefox driver) to develop an application. There are a lot of element.click() in my code. Sometimes that elements are not visible or not clickable make the application throws selenium exception.

To resolve that issue, i use WebdriverWait(driver, 10).until(...) for each single element which needs to be clicked.

My question is there is any other better way Or design pattern that can help me to solve the problem best.

Or at least i dont have to use WebdriverWait for each single element needs to be click().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot avoid `WebDriverWait`. If you send a webdriver click command, webdriver will blindly assume that "element is clickable". You need to instruct webdriver to wait because your element is special and needs some synchronization before it can click on it. I don't think you need to do this for every other element. You can incorporate [ExpectedConditions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) so that you can keep your code snippets manageable and small. So something like,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("foo"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The other option you can try other than clicking is hit enter on respective element, for that you can refer ID of that element.

`driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`

Answer (score 1):

use implicit wait instead of explicit wait and give the expected condition till the element doesn't visible on screen.

for more info you can check 
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Hope this will help you